# Установка memcache на Linux (Centos 7)

Tags: linux, centos7, memcached, memcache

На сервере крутится сайт на Wordpress
Пытаюсь подключить работу с плагином memcached,
но в коде плагина используется class Memcache

В итоге вылетает ошибка:
"Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Memcache' not found in ..."

Установил 
libmemcached-1.0.16-5.el.x86_64
memcahed-1.4.15-10.el7_3.1.x86_64

Службу memcached запустил, работает

Пытался установить пакет
php-pecl-memcache-3.0.8-4.el7.x86_64.rpm

Но вылетает ошибка
"Could not resolve host : mirrorlist.centos.org; Неизвесная ошибка"
 P.s у сервера нет доступа к интернету. 
Версия php 7.2.14 (cli)

Подскажите что сделать можно? Где взять то, что установится :) Или я возможно не то ищу...

Comment: pecl install memcached

Comment: На компьютере нет подключения к интернету

Comment: Скачать с https://pecl.php.net/package/memcached

Comment: И что дальше делать со скаченным архивом? Там нет ни файла .make ни .sh...

Comment: Там есть файлик README.markdown в нем написано как собрать и какие пакеты нужны

Comment: **memcache** или **memcached** ?
это разные вещи.
memcache с php7 не работает.